# How to list a blob that is inside a unknown folder?

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, directory-structure, blobstorage

I'm currently trying to list specific Blobs in my storage account.

For example my container contains blob in the following structure.

```
https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/<containername>/<folder1>/<folder2>/<folder3>/<file>
```

I want to receive all the blobs that are in a location of a third folder.

So if my container had the following blobs:

- animal/herbivore/tall/giraffe.txt
- animal/herbivore/zebra.txt
- car/electric/tesla/modely.txt
- car/electric/testla.txt

I only want to list:

- animal/herbivore/tall/giraffe.txt
- car/electric/tesla/modely.txt

```
 public async Task<List<string>> GetRecentGalleriesAsync()
        {
            var blobNames = new List<string>();
            await foreach (BlobHierarchyItem blobItem in _containerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(delimiter: "/", prefix: "*/*/*/"))
            {

                    blobNames.Add($"{_containerClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri}/{blobItem.Blob.Name}");
            }

            return blobNames;
        }
```

I have tried using different values for the delimiter and prefix on this method. Also, I believe the use of '*' is not allowed in the parameters. Unfortunately, I am left with an empty array. How can I only list the blobs that sits in a third folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to receive all the blobs that are in a location of a third folder.

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

In portal:

[image]

Have 2 folders with structure `<folder1><folder2><folder3><file>`

**`C# code which worked for me:`**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

BlobContainerClient conClient = new BlobContainerClient("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rith;AccountKey=BT2tkejS7Hi3aG7qRkHBqyG4q2qCHQ6Nlj5CUkJyETwjv8nJpnRTxHk8oExoW8gj2qEJctmDqvYy+ASt6qFsSA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", "rithwik");

string[] arr = new string[0];
char cc = '/';
await foreach (BlobItem b in conClient.GetBlobsAsync())
{ 
    
    int count = b.Name.Count(c => c == cc);
    if (count == 3)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref arr, arr.Length + 1);
        arr[arr.Length - 1] = b.Name;
        Console.WriteLine(b.Name);

    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

If you want to get from 4th Folder you need to keep equal to 4( in if condition) in the code.

**EDIT:**

**WITH LIST:**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

BlobContainerClient conClient = new BlobContainerClient("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rith;AccountKey=BT2tkejS7Hi3aG7qRkHBqyG4q2qCHQ6Nlj5CUkJyETwjv8nJpnRTxHk8oExoW8gj2qEJctmDqvYy+ASt6qFsSA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", "rithwik");

List<string> l = new List<string>();
char cc = '/';
await foreach (BlobItem b in conClient.GetBlobsAsync())
{ 
    
    int count = b.Name.Count(c => c == cc);
    if (count == 3)
    {
        l.Add(b.Name);
     
    }
}

foreach (var item in l)
{
    Console.WriteLine( item);
}
```

Comment: Why Array.Resize instead of List?

Comment: @Magnus, You can use anything(lists also), I am comfortable with arrays , so I have used it.

Comment: It creates a new array and copies the elements every time. A list would be more efficent. (Resizing handled internally and not every time.)

Comment: Your answer works, thank you. But just like @Magnus is saying, I indeed feel like this is not the most efficient way to do it. Can you reply your solution with List in code?

Comment: @Patrick de Jong, Updated answer(Check in EDIT Section).